# Azure SQL web server - virtual machine , server agent stops it self and so the jobs scheduled

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

With using Windows Azure SQL web server - virtual machine , I have small size SQL web server - VM for multiple databases.

I have noticed that server agent stops it self some how , and so the scheduled jobs were not executed on time.

Any solution / suggestion on this ?

Comment: Have you looked into the server's event logs? I'm sure you will find something there.

Answer (score 0):

As Gaurav indicated you can look at the Event Logs, but you can also inspect the SQL Server logs to get more insight if this is something deeper:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

-matt